# Why were my comments about the Dershowitz question inappropriate?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

In [How did Alan Dershowitz end up on Trumps' legal team?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/49845/how-did-alan-dershowitz-end-up-on-trumps-legal-team) , the question was two sentences long. I posted a comment, asking whether Trump has a bad record on civil liberties, because the question implied that there was a contradiction between Dershowitz being a civil libertarian, and him defending Trump against impeachment. It got deleted.

I posted a comment asking why the comment was deleted, and it too has been deleted.

The only comment posted by a moderator was "Comments deleted. Please try to keep your comments relevant to the question."

Why was my comment deleted, and is it inappropriate to ask for more details about the reasoning of the OP in asking a question?

I am asking about the comment here in meta, because I tried asking in chat, and did not get a reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were starting a discussion. As you should know by now, this website is not a discussion forum.

If you want to suggest improvements to a question, please do that directly. Don't do it in form of a rhetorical question which will then incite debate.

Comment: Why is it rhetorical to ask whether Trump has a bad record on civil liberties? Seems a legitimate question. Many accuse Trump of bad <insert anything> but that doesn't mean it is true. (Note: I don't see that possible bad record mentioned in the question - it seems as neutral as possible. But I don't agree with the "rhetorical" part in this answer. Upvoted nevertheless)